# How to use an S3 uri?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How to access an S3 bucket when presented with a uri like this?

s3://example-bucket/path/to/object

pasting this in the browser doesn't work. Is using the AWS cli the only way?

Comment: Who/what is providing you with an S3 URI? In most cases, you would either be given a pre-signed HTTPS URL to the S3 object or you would be given the S3 bucket and key directly (which obviously you could infer from the S3 URI, but it's more common to share bucket/key).

Comment: Understood, I just found this format in some internal documentation

Comment: @jarmod There is a big fat button at the top of the page when viewing obect details in the S3 console. Few people have any idea what the S3:// protocol is. Nobody has answered this yet. The URI is of the form S3://bucket/prefix/object - it is not https://

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Citing an answer on this [forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=93828), you can use the bucket name and the object name to create a browser link.

```
http(s)://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<object>
http(s)://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/<object>
```

For the example you mentioned,

```
# s3://example-bucket/path/to/object
http(s)://example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/object
http(s)://s3.amazonaws.com/example-bucket/path/to/object
```

However, the required permissions should be made available to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS CLI as you said, but there are a plethora of other clients available. My picks are:

- [s4cmd](https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd) is very handy as a command line tool
- as for the GUI tools I'd recommend [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/)